# Assigning $_POST variables to PHP Mailer() Parameters

Tags: php, post

How can one assign $_POST variables to the PHP mailer() 'From:' header parameter?

Here's what I tried:

```
$toEmail="email@example.com";
$formSubject=$_POST["esubject"];
$formComment=$_POST["comment"];
$header= 'From: $_POST["eaddress"]';

mail($toEmail, $formSubject, $formComment, $header)) {
```

The subject and comments are working correctly, but the From: turns the variable into a string.

Comment: It would as your using single quotes `'`, though your code opens you to header injection, which your host wont like once a bot turns your contact form into a spam relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$header= 'From:' . $_POST["eaddress"];
```

In your code, `$_POST["eaddress"]` was in a single quote, it would not be evaluated.